# Is this closed under (+) and ( $\times$ ) when n is an integer and n $>$ 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n\Bbb Z = \{ nx \mid x \in \Bbb Z \}$

This is what I have: (which makes sense to me)

> Let $x, y \in \Bbb Z$. We get that $nx$ and $ny$. Then, $nx + ny  = n(x+y)$ and since $(x+y) \in \Bbb Z$ it is closed under addition.
>
> Let $x, y \in\Bbb Z$. We get that $nx$ and $ny$. Then, $nx\cdot ny$  =
> $n$ $(nxy)$ and since $(nxy) \in\Bbb Z$ it is closed under multiplication.

Is that alright? I'm in finals so I have to be sure I get every aspect of this.

Comment: $(nx)(by) = n^2(xy) = n(nxy)$!

Comment: How can we tell whether it's all right, when you have never made a clear statement of what it is that you are trying to do? Please edit your question so that it actually has a question in it.

Comment: @MattSamuel it's a very simple mistake that I noticed later on.. I don't think the cynical comment was necessary, but thank you anyways.

Comment: (nx)(ny)=n(nxy) ..and $nxy \in Z$ so it is closed under multiplication.. Except that all ok

Comment: @RobertLewis what do you mean in the comment?

Comment: @PhilJones:  the original version had $nx \cdot ny = nxy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the mistakes it is fine.

- Notice $(nx)\cdot(ny) = n(nxy)$, not $n(xy)$.
- "We have that $nx$ and $ny$." (are what?).

Other than that you might want to include a justification for why you can say $(x+y)\in \Bbb Z$ and $(nxy)\in\Bbb Z$.   What property of $\Bbb Z$ allows this?

---

PS: You only stated that $n>0$.  Is it supposed to be assumed to be integer?  Because if it is not, you may not have multiplicative closure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I edited the question saying that n has to be a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should state what you are trying to prove.  Presumably you want to prove that $n\Bbb Z$ is closed under addition and multiplication.  The way to do that is to take two arbitrary elements of $n\Bbb Z$ and show their sum and product are also elements of $n\Bbb Z$.  You would start with "Suppose $x,y \in n\Bbb z$.  Then there exist $m,p$ with $x=nm, y=np$."  Now can you see how to show $x+y \in n\Bbb Z$?